# How do I use Firebug's or Firefox DevTools' inspector to view just one element?

Tags: html, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I can delete a single `<div>` element by selecting it in Firebug's *HTML* panel or within the *Inspector* panel of the Firefox DevTools and pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>, but is there a way to delete all elements except one?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with this? Do you want to extract a part of a page including the related CSS as described in [issue 2366](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2366) for Firebug? Or do you want to filter the HTML tree displayed within those tools to only display a part of the page (but keep the page itself unchanged)?

Comment: Hi @SebastianZartner.  Thanks for trying to help, but pbrosset nailed it.

Comment: My answer would have been similar, though I wanted to ensure first I understand what you actually want to achieve. Anyway, good @pbrosset could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see a use case for deleting all HTML elements except one, but there are several ways you could do that in Firefox DevTools:

- Select each element one by one in the tree and press <kbd>Del</kbd> each time.
- Or select the root node, right-click, and select the "Edit as HTML" contextual menu, then in the editor box that appears, remove the HTML you don't want to see anymore, and submit (`<kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Doing this however may end up removing a lot of the styling applied to the remaining element, and it may not appear as it originally was after you do this.

Maybe what you want to do instead is "isolate" an element visually in the page so that it's the only one that's visible anymore. If so, there's no feature in devtools to do this, but it's easily achievable by adding some CSS in the Style-Editor panel. Assuming the element you want to isolate has the id "my-id", you could do this:

```css
* { visibility: hidden; } #my-id { visibility: visible; }
```

Comment: The bottom line is what I was looking for.  Thank you.